# Chainlink node external adapter job not returning value

Tags: smartcontracts, chainlink

I am following the "Chainlink Hackathon | Building and using External Adapters" video tutorial (Oct 2021) and have done the following:

-Successfully set up and ran my own Chainlink node (per "Chainlink Hackathon | Running a Chainlink node, 1.0.0 update" video tutorial [Oct 2021].

-Created `Oracle.sol` contract and `setFulfillmentPermission` to `true`

-Successfully created Job Run on my node for the `Get > Uint256` example

-Added Eth to my node.

Added the following bridge to my node:

```
URL http://localhost:8080
Confirmations   0
Minimum Contract Payment    0
Outgoing Token  OKKkCQpl84Kiw38WNZ77fg1UKLgyB5+c
```

Added the Job definition:

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "soccer-data-ea-2"
contractAddress = "0x4664A91f79999fd9DD4587dDf3daA3D01Ec50825"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type=bridge name=hackathon requestData="{\\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\": {\\"PlayerId\\": $(decode_cbor.PlayerId)}}"]
    parse        [type="jsonparse" path="data,0,Games" data="$(fetch)"]
    encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(uint256 value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(parse) }"]
    encode_tx    [type="ethabiencode"
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="0x4664A91f79999fd9DD4587dDf3daA3D01Ec50825" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
externalJobID = "88cafd3a-e04b-453d-9521-26372a9c1ab0"
```

Added my Oracle address and JobId (without dashes) to the APIConsumer.sol contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
 */

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
    uint256 public games;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Oracle: 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8 (Chainlink Devrel   
     * Node)
     * Job ID: d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747
     * Fee: 0.1 LINK
     */
    constructor() {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x4664A91f79999fd9DD4587dDf3daA3D01Ec50825;
        jobId = "88cafd3ae04b453d952126372a9c1ab0";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)
    }
    
    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
     */
    function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        
        
        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        // {"RAW":
        //   {"ETH":
        //    {"USD":
        //     {
        //      "VOLUME24HOUR": xxx.xxx,
        //     }
        //    }
        //   }
        //  }
        request.add("PlayerId", "90026531");
        
        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
      
        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */ 
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _games) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        games = _games;
    }

    // function withdrawLink() external {} - Implement a withdraw function to avoid locking your LINK in the contract
}
```

I deployed and sent LINK to the APIConsumer contract, hit `requestVolumeData`, funded the transaction, however the job never runs and I get no error. Have been reviewing the tutorial and building it from scratch several times but the bridge external adapter on my node never runs the job.

Not sure why it's not working?

Comment: This means your oracle address or job id is off.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the fee to 1 * 10**18 in your consumer contract, or add a line to your `.env` file and reboot your CL node:

```
MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT_LINK_JUELS=100000000000000000
```

which means, change the minimum link payment to 0.1LINK globally.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:
in your consumer contract:
set fee = 1 * 10 ** 18; not 0.1
or
in your .env file:
MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT_LINK_JUELS=100000000000000000
set fee = 1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).